# Problema retardo en render react-router UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, useeffect

Buen dia a todos! Tengo un problema y creo que es con el useEffect y el store. La cuestion es esta tengo un ruta http:.../algo/:id el cual dependiendo el id del param me tendria que renderizar data diferente. Pero al renderizar por unos segundo aparece el render anterior. EJ:http:.../algo/1 me tendria que renderiza una A y en http:.../algo/2 me tendria que renderiza una B. El problema cuando voy de http:.../algo/1 hacia http:.../algo/2 me renderiza por unos milisegundos A y luego pasa a B y asi a la viceversa.

```
const Gallery = (props) => {
  const id = props.match.params.id;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const gallery = useSelector((state) => state.gallery);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getInfoGallery(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>--GALLERY--</p>
      <div>
        {gallery.length === 0 ? (
          <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
        ) : (
          gallery.map((el) => {
            return (
              <div key={el.id}>
                <p>{el.name}</p>
                <p>{el.photo}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: un string, pienso poner una imagen mas adelante pero por ahora solo me trae un string

Comment: Deberías controlar que mientras esté cargando no muestre nada... quizas en el getInfoGallery seteas algun "isLoading" o algo por el estilo?

Comment: perfecto ahi voy a intentar agregando un loading

Comment: @g.4 estoy usando la v5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisé el caso, comparto mis notas.

---

#### Latencia en DOM render con react router Link

El componente `Link` cambia la `URL` manipulando la HTML5 History API, pero el contenido del componente enrutado en `Link` puede parecer no mostrarse (render) en sincronía con el cambio de la URL.

> El problema cuando voy de http:.../algo/1 hacia http:.../algo/2 me renderiza por unos milisegundos A y luego pasa a B y asi a la viceversa.

Hay una **latencia** entre el cambio de rutas con respecto al render para cada componente.

Puede parecer imperceptible a cierto tipo de datos, pero al  manipular imagenes y su carga, esta latencia es muy evidente en el explorador, su causa parece ser asincrónica ya que la imagen se carga desde otro servidor.

Es decir, no se sabe cuanto tiempo va a tomar la imagen en cargarse por completo en el componente, pero si se puede saber cuando ya esta cargada.

Cabe mencionar que no logré resolver el problema de la latencia, ni con `Suspense/lazy`, ni con banderas tipo `isLoading` controladas por estado local.

#### Propuesta

La siguiente propuesta puede ser útil para cualquier tipo de dato que necesite ser pintado en el DOM, pero se muestra el caso de uso para imagenes.

La única forma de *evitar que el usuario viera la misma imagen por unos instantes aunque la ruta ya hubiese cambiado*(click en Link/boton etc...), fue accediendo al evento `onLoad` propio de  elemento  `img`.

Luego, asignar un valor de estado con este elemento `img` para posteriormente, pintarlo en el re-render:

```
//pseudocodigo Gallery
function Gallery(props){

const [imgCard, setImgCard] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let newListItem = document.createElement('img');
    newListItem.src = props.url;
    newListItem.onload = function () {
            setImgCard(newListItem)
    }
  },[props.url])


  return {imgCard}
);
```

Entonces, la secuencia del componente `Gallery`:

- El usuario entra en una nueva ruta, su componente renderiza `{imgCard}`, su estado inicial es `null`, no hay nada.(Aquí se puede implementar una bandera `isLoading` o similar). El usuario deja de ver el asset(imagen) que esta en la ruta anterior.
- Se dispara `useEffect`, ahi se crea un elemento `img`, se asignan valores a sus propiedades como `url` y demás.
- Se invoca al metodo `onload` para disparar un re-render del componente una vez que la imagen ya este cargada en el mismo.
- Se dispara el re-render, `imgCard` ya cambio su valor de estado por un elemento `img` con propiedades asignadas, el cual ya ha sido previamente cargado en `useEffect`.

Puede que haya una mejor manera de trabajar esta latencia en datos, los cuales necesiten ser pintados en el DOM al cambiar de ruta.

Otras respuestas/comentarios/aportes son bienvenidos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! sos un genio!